# Simple bank-atm system design OOP

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented

For practicing designing systems I created a simple bank ATM system.

I didn't want to make it to complicated so I left out things like cash bin per ATM and opening cash trays, etc. I also wanted to neglect APIs to validate pins, etc. (it's just a function that will always return True). I wanted to focus on classes and methods.

So in my example I have

- an `Account` class which has an account number, a balance and withdraw and deposit functions.
- a `Card` class which has accounts and a select account function which will search for the account number on the card and then return it.
- an `ATM` class which has the following variables: `card_inserted`, `card_validated`, `current_account`, `current_card` and the main function are `perform_request` (which will either give out the balance, deposit or withdraw money), `validate_pin` (which will make the call to the API, mocked in my code), `select_account` (which will select an account from the card)

I did write a test for it and it worked. I was wondering if I could get some feedback on that (not the test, I know I can do lot's of things to make the tests better but that was just a quick and dirty version of it)?

atm.py:

```
def validate_api(card_nr, pin):
    # validate account nr and pin
    # return true or fale
    return True

class Card():
    def __init__(self, accounts = []):
        self.accounts = accounts

    def select_account(self, account_nr):
        # check if there is a built in filter func in python

        for account in self.accounts:
            if account.account_nr == account_nr:
                return account

        raise Exception("Account number invalid")

class Account():
    def __init__(self, account_nr = None):
        self.account_nr = account_nr
        self.balance = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount


class ATM():
    def __init__(self):
        self.card_inserted = False
        self.card_validated = False
        self.current_account = None
        self.current_card = None

    def validate_card_and_pin(self):
        if not self.card_inserted:
            raise Exception('Card must be inserted first')

        if self.card_validated is False:
            raise Exception
            # raise Exception("Card not validated")

    def insert_card(self, bank_card):
        # code to accept card
        self.card_inserted = True
        self.current_card = bank_card

    def eject_card(self):
        self.end_session()
        # code to push card out

    def validate_pin(self, pin):
        if not self.card_inserted:
            raise Exception('Card must be inserted first')

        # card is inserted, pin has to be validated
        # post pin and card number to api
        # response will be saved in validated variable

        validated = validate_api(card_nr=0,pin=0)

        if validated == False:
            self.card_validated = False
            return self.card_validated

        self.card_validated = True
        return self.card_validated

    def select_account(self, account_nr):
        self.validate_card_and_pin()
        if self.current_card is None:
            raise Exception("no card in ATM")

        if self.card_validated is False:
            raise Exception("card not validated")

        current_account = self.current_card.select_account(account_nr)
        self.current_account = current_account


    '''
    1 = check balance
    2 = deposit money
    3 = withdraw money
    '''
    def perform_request(self, request, amount = 0):
        self.validate_card_and_pin()
        if request == 1:
            return self.check_balance()
        elif request == 2:
            return self.accept_cash(amount)
        elif request == 3:
            return self.give_out_cash(amount)
        else:
            raise Exception("invalid request")

    def accept_cash(self, amount):
        # open cash tray
        # count cash
        self.current_account.deposit(amount)
        return amount

    def give_out_cash(self, amount):
        # count cash
        # open tray
        self.current_account.withdraw(amount)
        return amount

    def check_balance(self):
        return self.current_account.balance

    def end_session(self):
        self.card_inserted = False
        self.card_validated = False
        self.current_account = None
        self.current_card = None
        return True
```

And here the test:

```
 def test_depositing_50_and_withdrawing_20():
        checking = Account(1)
        saving = Account(2)
        bank_card = Card([checking, saving])
        atm = ATM()
    
        atm.insert_card(bank_card)
        atm.validate_pin("123")
        atm.select_account(1)
        atm.perform_request(2, 50)
        if atm.perform_request(1) is not 50:
            raise Exception("depositing function doesn't work")
        atm.end_session()
    
        atm.insert_card(bank_card)
        atm.validate_pin("123")
        atm.select_account(1)
        atm.perform_request(3, 20)
        if atm.perform_request(1) is not 30:
            raise Exception("withdrawing function doesn't work")
    
        atm.select_account(2)
        atm.validate_pin("123")
        atm.perform_request(2, 10)
    
        if atm.perform_request(1) is not 10:
            raise Exception("depositing function doesn't work")
    
        print("Test successful")
```

Comment: On another level I would like to add that banks don't keep track of a balance by editing a single value. Instead they use a form of [event sourcing](https://eventsourcing.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/introduction.html#what-is-event-sourcing) to keep track of all changes as well and use the event sourcing to calculate what the resulting balance should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Card():
```

You don't need parenthesis in the class declarations. Also, while most of your formatting is pretty good, there's a couple nitpicky things. When supplying a default argument, [there shouldn't be spaces around the `=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), and there [should be two blank lines between top-level definitions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines).

---

You should really [never have a mutable default parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) like you do in:

```
def __init__(self, accounts = []):
```

In this case, since you never modify `self.accounts`, you're safe. If you ever added an `add_account` method that associated an account with a card by `append`ing to `self.accounts`, you'd see that every `Card` in your program that was created using the default argument would change when that method is run.

I'd change it to:

```
def __init__(self, accounts=None):  # Default to None
    self.accounts = accounts or []  #  then create the list inside the method instead
```

---

```
# check if there is a built in filter func in python
```

There are multiple ways of using some fancy shortcut function to find the first element that satisfies a predicate, but honestly, I'd just stick to what you have. A `for` loop with an early return is pretty easy to understand. Since you want to raise an exception if an account isn't found, the other ways get a little bit sloppy. If you were fine having it return `None` on an error, you could use:

```
def select_account(self, account_nr):
    return next((account for account in self.accounts if account.account_nr == account_nr), None)
```

`next` attempts to grab the first element of an iterator that you give it. I'm giving it a generator expression, that will produce an element only if `account.account_nr == account_nr` is true. The `None` as the second argument is a default value if nothing is found. I still prefer the iterative `for` style though.

---

In `Account`, you're allowing `None` to be used as an account number. This strikes me as the kind of field that should not be "nullable", or be allowed to be omitted when creating an object. I think a (unique, existing) account number is pretty fundamental to the idea of a bank account. I would get rid of the default and force the user to supply that information when creating an account. It may be helpful though to have a second `starting_balance` parameter that lets the user to set the starting account balance, and allow that to default to `0`.

---

`validate_card_and_pin` is a misleading name. It doesn't seem to do the validations. It expects that the validations have already been done and that the internal `self.card_validated` state is already set. `assert_is_validated` may be a better name for what it's doing.

---

I think `validate_pin` could be made clearer. Note how a lot of the code at the bottom is duplicated. You're setting `card_validated` to whatever `validated` is, then returning that value. The function can be simply:

```
def validate_pin(self, pin):
    if not self.card_inserted:
        raise Exception('Card must be inserted first')
    
    self.card_validated = validate_api(card_nr=0,pin=0)
    return self.card_validated
```

---

I'd maybe rethink throwing exceptions from the methods. In my eyes, a PIN being entered wrong for example isn't really *exceptional*. I'm a fan of returning `None` as a error indicator in cases where a function can only fail in one way; like `validate_pin`. You just have to be in the habit of identifying when a function returns `None`, and handling that case properly.

If you do want to use exceptions though, throwing a plain `Exception` is a bad idea. This makes it more difficult for the caller to catch and handle specifically exceptions from your code. I think this is an appropriate case to create [custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python). Something like:

```
class PINValidationFailed(RuntimeError):
    pass
```

Then the caller can catch specifically that exception to handle PIN failures.

---

```
'''
1 = check balance
2 = deposit money
3 = withdraw money
'''
def perform_request(self, request, amount = 0):
```

If that's intended as a docstring, it needs to be inside the function and indented:

```
def perform_request(self, request, amount=0):
    '''
    1 = check balance
    2 = deposit money
    3 = withdraw money
    '''
```

---

I think `if self.card_validated is False:` is clearer as simply `if not self.card_validated:`.

---

After touching this up, I'm left with:

```
def validate_api(card_nr, pin):
    # validate account nr and pin
    # return true or false
    return True


class Card:
    def __init__(self, accounts=None):
        self.accounts = accounts or []

    def select_account(self, account_nr):
        return next((account for account in self.accounts if account.account_nr == account_nr), None)


class Account:
    def __init__(self, account_nr, starting_balance=0):
        self.account_nr = account_nr
        self.balance = starting_balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount


class ATM:
    def __init__(self):
        self.card_inserted = False
        self.card_validated = False
        self.current_account = None
        self.current_card = None

    def validate_card_and_pin(self):
        if not self.card_inserted:
            raise RuntimeError('Card must be inserted first')

        if not self.card_validated:
            raise RuntimeError("Card not validated")

    def insert_card(self, bank_card):
        # code to accept card
        self.card_inserted = True
        self.current_card = bank_card

    def eject_card(self):
        self.end_session()
        # code to push card out

    def validate_pin(self, pin):
        if not self.card_inserted:
            raise RuntimeError('Card must be inserted first')

        self.card_validated = validate_api(card_nr=0, pin=0)
        return self.card_validated


    def select_account(self, account_nr):
        self.validate_card_and_pin()
        if self.current_card is None:
            raise RuntimeError("no card in ATM")

        if self.card_validated is False:
            raise RuntimeError("card not validated")

        current_account = self.current_card.select_account(account_nr)
        self.current_account = current_account


    def perform_request(self, request, amount=0):
        '''
        1 = check balance
        2 = deposit money
        3 = withdraw money
        '''
        self.validate_card_and_pin()
        if request == 1:
            return self.check_balance()
        elif request == 2:
            return self.accept_cash(amount)
        elif request == 3:
            return self.give_out_cash(amount)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("invalid request")

    def accept_cash(self, amount):
        # open cash tray
        # count cash
        self.current_account.deposit(amount)
        return amount

    def give_out_cash(self, amount):
        # count cash
        # open tray
        self.current_account.withdraw(amount)
        return amount

    def check_balance(self):
        return self.current_account.balance

    def end_session(self):
        self.card_inserted = False
        self.card_validated = False
        self.current_account = None
        self.current_card = None
        return True
```

Comment: dude, thank you so much! this is exactly what I wanted to know, I don't have much experience with stuff like that, thank you for taking the time to answer so detail oriented, especially for the nitpicking syntax stuff! I was also thinking if there is a better way to do `assert_is_validated`, was reading about decorators, is this something I could use here?

Comment: @Tom No problem. Glad to help. Hopefully someone with a more OOP background can make comments about that aspect.

Comment: @Tom If you want to have it set up where you're just checking the state of the object before allowing something to happen, I don't think having an `assert-thing` function at the top of the method is *necessarily* bad. I've certainly done it, and I've seen it done in standard libraries.

Comment: @Tom [Here](https://github.com/carcigenicate/AI/blob/11b706866c95a7512c51da5e096a22a5e31b664a/src/ai_retry/genetic_algorithm/sequence.clj#L42) is actually an example of me doing it awhile ago (`check-gene-compatibility`). Note I use it in `breed` right below that.

Comment: ahhh okk, thank you!